# React Router v4: Sending requests when navigation changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm coding an authentication with react-router v4 and I'm using the PrivateRoute with render props, like the documentation: [Redirects (Auth)](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

**What I'm trying to do is:** Whenever the user navigates to a route, I want to dispatch an action to make a request to the backend to verify if he's logged in.

Like this:

```
// App.js
class App extends Component {
  checkAuth = () => {
    const { dispatch, } = this.props;
    // callback to dispatch
  }

  render() {
    const props = this.props;

    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />

            <PrivateRoute
              exact
              path="/dashboard"
              component={Dashboard}
              checkIsLoggedIn={this.checkAuth}
            />

            {/* ... other private routes here */}

          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

In PrivateRoute.js I'm listening the route to check if it changes, but when a route changes, this function is called too many times, and that's a problem to dispatch an action to make a request.

```
// PrivateRoute.js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, checkIsLoggedIn, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => {
      props.history.listen((location, action) => {

        if (checkIsLoggedIn) {
          // Here I check if the route changed, but it render too many times to make a request
          checkIsLoggedIn(); // here is the callback props
        }
      });

      if (auth.login.isLoggedIn) {
        return <Component {...props} />;
      } else {
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }} />
      }


    }
    }
  />
);
```

I need a help to figure it out a good way to call the backend whenever the route changes.

Comment: you can make a request to your backend in the method `componentDidMount` of our _Dashboard_ component

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas but I want to make a request in every private route that the user navigates

Comment: `PrivateRoute` is a custom defined React component. It has nothing to do with react-router. Change it into a stateful class and add your authentication call in its `componentDidMount` method.

Comment: @FisNaN should I change it to a class using render props or HoC?

Comment: a hoc to check if the has perm would be a good approach

Comment: render prop or hoc doesn't matter, either will do what you need. also... you have `<Route` and `history.listen`. Route is *already* listening to history so your code is adding an additional history listener on every route change.

Comment: @azium could you provide an example to do it in a good way?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can. BTW a normal approach is to login once, save cookie. After that, only redirect to login page if  the session expired. Checking login every time is very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a [Higher Order Component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) is a very clean way to do this. This way, you won't need to create a separate `PrivateRoute` component, and it would take only one line of change to convert any Component from public to protected, or vice versa.

Something like this should work:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export function withAuth(WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                isUserLoggedIn: false,
                isLoading: true
            };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            // Check for authentication when the component is mounted
            this.checkAuthentication();
        }

        checkAuthentication() {
            // Put some logic here to check authentication
            // You can make a server call if you wish,
            // but it will be faster if you read the logged-in state
            // from cookies or something.
            // Making a server call before every protected component,
            // will be very expensive, and will be a poor user experience.
            this.setState({
                isUserLoggedIn: true,       // Set to true or false depending upon the result of your auth check logic
                isLoading: false
            });
        }

        render() {
            // Optionally, you can add logic here to show a common loading animation,
            // or anything really, while the component checks for auth status.
            // You can also return null, if you don't want any special handling here.
            if (this.state.isLoading) return (<LoadingAnimation />);

            // This part will load your component if user is logged in,
            // else it will redirect to the login route
            if (this.state.isUserLoggedIn) {
                return <WrappedComponent authData={this.state} {...this.props} />;
            } else {
                return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }} />;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have that component in place, all you need to do is use the HOC in any component that you wish to have protected. For example, in your case, the export line in your `Dashboard` file would be something like this:

```
/* Dashboard.js */
class Dashboard extends React.Component { ... }

export default withAuth(Dashboard);
```

and in your `App`, you can use a simple `Route` component:

```
<Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
```

Your `App` does not need to care about which routes are protected, and which ones aren't. In fact, only the actual components need to know that they are protected.

Hope this helps. Cheers! :)

Comment: Using HoC is a cool idea, but I'm trying to avoid using HoC because of the huge problem: if I use another HoC that has a prop with the same name in 'withAuth', it will conflict! I still don't know if using HoC is a good idea because of the props conflicts..

Comment: I think that's a relatively minor problem to have compared to the benefits you get by abstracting away the auth logic from your `App` component. You can rename the `authData` prop to something obscure, or consciously ensure that there are no prop conflicts in your protected components. Else, if you feel that your `Dashboard` or other components don't need to consume `authData`, you can even choose to not pass it along at all.